# Need help identifying sprouts from random seeds

Tags: identification

[image]

[image]

I casually put some vegetable/fruit seeds on some cups but I wasn’t able to keep track which was which. Are these eggplants?

Comment: Pinch off one leaf and crush it.  Tell us what it smells like.  Also, are the stems rounded or more square.   Thank you.

Comment: Please describe the seed.

Comment: @GardenGems - I crushed a leaf and it didn’t smell like anything in particular. I don’t think it had a smell or it was too mild for me to detect. 
                

ColinBeckingham - I don’t remember the seed I put in this specific cup.

Comment: I like Colin's style of questioning the best.  Where the seeds large like pumpkin seeds or almost dust like in-between.   Also, gently dig around in the soil for any seeds that didn't germinate or parts of seeds that did.   Leave any seeds still attached to the plants roots alone.    Just look down and describe what you see.     You would not happen to be doing this for a class project?

Comment: @GardenGem - I tried to dig around and I didn’t find any seeds left in the cup. I remember the seeds I threw randomly were mostly dust-like and there were some guava seeds I put in some other cups. I just realized I forgot to write down that the stem of the plant is not round but square-ish. 

Not to worry, this is not for any school project. I just wanted to plant seeds from veggies and fruits at home.

Comment: Often plants in the Lamiaceae family, in other words the mint & nettle family have square stems.   In many instances they have a particular smell, but not always.   When you press/rub coleus leaves between your fingers it does not have a particular mint smell, but a woody smell, but still a smell that is noticeable.  It has a square stems and in the same family.    You maybe looking at something in this large family.   Many are very vigour growers.   Your leaves reminded me of a mint.

Answer (score 1):

You have Basil, I can tell by the leaves.

Answer (score 0):

We can say pretty definitely that it is not eggplant aubergine. Look up eggplant images and you will find first that the eggplant leaf is kinda dull where these are shiny, eggplant leaf is distinctly lobed (bumpy edges) even when juvenile, and the petioles really stand erect where your leaf shoots are quite horizontal.

Since you presumably used seed from a fruit, it can't possibly be annual stuff like basil or carrot or cabbage, so that leaves common stuff like orange, apple, pomegranate, kiwi and so on. What kind of stuff runs through your kitchen on a regular basis?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a eggplant, looks like lemon plant. let it grow for sometime, the leaves will have fragrance of lemon than.